# text to explode and loop php result is wrong

Tags: php, arrays, explode

text to explode and loop php result is wrong 
but i try to this text to result 1 to 50 line
but result is more duplicate

```
<?php
$text   = "1*10 11*20 21*30 31*40 41*50";
$textAr = explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $text));
$textAr = array_filter($textAr, 'trim');
foreach ($textAr as $line) {
    $pieces = explode("*", $line);
    list($first, $last) = array_pad(explode('*', $line, 2), 2, null);
    $add = 1;
    for ($i = $first; $i <= $last; $i += $add) {
        $array[] = array(
            'count' => $i
        );
    }
    $codes = $array;
    foreach ($codes as $code) {
        echo $code['count'];
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

**Results :** 150 lines

> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,‌​17,18,19,20,1,2,3,4,‌​5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1‌​3,14,15,16,17,18,19,‌​20,21,22,23,24,25,26‌​,27,28,29,30,1,2,3,4‌​,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,‌​13,14,15,16,17,18,19‌​,20,21,22,23,24,25,2‌​6,27,28,29,30,31,32,‌​33,34,35,36,37,38,39‌​,40,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,‌​9,10,11,12,13,14,15,‌​16,17,18,19,20,21,22‌​,23,24,25,26,27,28,2‌​9,30,31,32,33,34,35,‌​36,37,38,39,40,41,42‌​,43,44,45,46,47,48,4‌​9,50

but I want results but i want result 1-50 with no duplicates

Comment: Please indent your code, it's pretty unreadable for now. Btw show an exemple of result, and explain why it's a wrong one.

Comment: resulr is 150 lines

Comment: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50

Comment: but i want result 1-50 on this text input

Comment: Well, that looks ok since you use `$array[]` which will add into the array all the `$i` from `$first`to `$last`. Btw you should just Edit your post and add those example inside [I got that, I want that, because of That]

Comment: single input ok when multiple line result wrong

Comment: I've post and answer upvote and validate it if it does the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to move the print outside of the foreach loop.
This code will add the number from 1 to 10, 11 to 20 .. etc according to the input [which is $text].
And print all of them at the end.

```
<?php
$text   = "1*10
11*20
21*30
31*40
41*50";
$textAr = explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $text));
$textAr = array_filter($textAr, 'trim');

foreach ($textAr as $line) {
    $pieces = explode("*", $line);
    list($first, $last) = array_pad(explode('*', $line, 2), 2, null);

    $add = 1;
    for ($i = $first; $i <= $last; $i += $add) {
        $array[] = array(
            'count' => $i
        );
    }


}

$codes = $array;
foreach ($codes as $code) {
    echo $code['count'];
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Result :

> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5
> 6
> 7
> 8
> 9
> 10
> 11
> 12
> 13
> 14
> 15
> 16
> 17
> 18
> 19
> 20
> 21
> 22
> 23
> 24
> 25
> 26
> 27
> 28
> 29
> 30
> 31
> 32
> 33
> 34
> 35
> 36
> 37
> 38
> 39
> 40
> 41
> 42
> 43
> 44
> 45
> 46
> 47
> 48
> 49
> 50

Example : http://ideone.com/Tk052M

Comment: just copy the results from that link and paste them here

Comment: yes i mistake outside of the foreach loop works perfect Thanks